# Bootstrap 4 Navbar Taller On Tablet Screen amongst split behavior

Tags: javascript, css, bootstrap-4, font-awesome, nav

I'm using Bootstrap 4 for my personal web site.  The problem I am having is that on my tablet the top menu splits into 2 lines:

- The "font awesome" icon is displayed in the top row
- Immediately below each icon is a row of each section name the font awesome icon represents.

[image]

Is it possible to force this to be j (such as what I see on my computer screen) or otherwise to become the 3 line menu instead of splitting into 2 lines?  I want the menu to have a maximum height of the computer screen version I see.

The web site is [here](https://rons-home.net/en/blog)

What I am wanting to be displayed on the tablet version is a 3 line menu someone will click on the top left and the top right be the "search" and search submit button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Navigations with lots of content are tricky... but this is what I think will get you what you're looking for and will be proper way to display such a navigation:

**(1)** You got a lot of elements and you want a '3 line menu' (which is called a burger menu or a hamburger menu) on a tablet; this is done via the property: `navbar-expand-xl` which basically communicates that menu should be expanded from "burger mode" to "expanded mode" when the device resolution is 1200px. You make this change on your navigation element, like:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark fixed-top bg-dark">
```

**(2)** Next, when the menu is expanded, we see 3 lines for each element, icon and it's name underneath, you can style it using the following css:

```
.navbar-expand-xl .navbar-nav { display: -webkit-inline-box; }
```

... to continue to force "displayed all on one line"... you may have to set this property for different screen sizes (***if you don't do point #1 of my answer***)

```
.navbar-expand-lg .navbar-nav { display: -webkit-inline-box; }
/* or */
.navbar-expand-md .navbar-nav { display: -webkit-inline-box; }
```

Comment: That is corrected.  But the 'Search' also needs a similar fix.  Would you be able to tell me how to do this to search as well?

Comment: what do you want to do with the search?

Comment: The same as the menu items.  The input box and submit button beside each other.

Comment: (1) `@media (min-width: 992px) {
.mb-lg-0, .my-lg-0 { display: contents; }
}`
 and 
(2) `.form-control{
    width: auto;
}` - good luck :)